# Does Vert.x have plans addressing the deprecation of biased locking in Java 15?

Tags: synchronization, vert.x, biased-locking

I am in advanced stages of writing a Clojure HTTP library built on top of Vert.x. I was just made aware of the [deprecation of "biased locking"](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/374) starting from Java 15.
I understand that Vert.x relies on it quite heavily, and I was wondering are there any plans in the pipeline to address this issue? It sounds like the impact on performance will be quite noticeable.

Comment: Perhaps ask the devs at Vert.x.

Answer (score 2):

1. Deprecation doesn't mean "total removal"

> The options will still be accepted and acted upon, but a deprecation
> warning will be issued

2. Vert.x, in fact, doesn't rely on biased locking that heavily. You'll see that biased locking is mentioned in comments of some important classes, that's true, but that's mostly around steams:
   https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/search?p=1&q=Biased&unscoped_q=Biased
3. Impact of biased locking is minor, but that's me running the [benchmarks](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/master/BENCHMARKING.md), so experience may vary. You can run the benchmark yourself, if you have an hour to spare (each cycle took me 28 minutes to complete)