# Is JMC's "Java Monitor Blocked" caused by vert.x Http1xServerConnection problem?

Tags: java, vert.x, blocking, nonblocking, jmc

I do profile my vert.x based http service and noticed in JMC that all my envelop threads(aka verticles) produce lots of "Java Monitor Blocked" events in class io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection. Javadoc of this class says: "The internal state is protected using the synchronized keyword. If always used on the same event loop, then we benefit from biased locking which makes the overhead of synchronized near zero.". I noticed that JDK17 I use has BiasedLocking turned off. I try to run test with turned on BiasedLocking but nothing changed. It also says that BiasedLocking was deprecated and could be removed. In the internet I found this SO topic which says that it's fine that vert.x uses synchronized in some classes [Does Vert.x have plans addressing the deprecation of biased locking in Java 15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63868643/does-vert-x-have-plans-addressing-the-deprecation-of-biased-locking-in-java-15)

My question is that does the JMC profile looks good or I should worry and there is a performance issues in my code? [image]

Comment: you might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63883926/2133695

Comment: I saw it, that SO mentioned in my message. My question is more about is it okay to see such amount of "Java Monitor Blocked" events in JMC?

Comment: Can you share a simple reproducer on GitHub?